# Python using diffrent pip version that in PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, linux, pip

I installed python 2.7 on mine shared host (it already had python 2.6 but they didnt want to upgrade it or install any packages) and pip. Configured PYTHONPATH and PATH in .bashrc. I dont have root access to this machine.

When I am checking sys.path with mine python installation it does not reference anywhere this shared location.

I checked commands:

```
which python
which pip
```

output:

> /home/mgx/python27/bin/pip

and both provides me to mine installation but using

```
pip --version
```

output:

> pip 1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-1.1-py2.6.egg (python 2.6)

I can see that it using version from /usr/ not mine. How can I force it to use mine pip version? When I try to install with mine pip version by direct address it everything works but the short pip command is using wrong one. Also strange is that 'which' command show the good one...

Edit: output of cat $(which pip) and outputs of previous commands

```
#!/home/mgx/python27/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==1.4.1','console_scripts','pip'
__requires__ = 'pip==1.4.1'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
    )
```

Comment: `pip` is usually just a trivial Python script that imports and runs the real code via `pkg_resources`. Can you `cat $(which pip)` and paste it here? In particular, does it have a shebang line that points to the wrong Python and/or uses env instead of pointing directly?

Comment: Posted in question.
Hm.. this one is for sure right one as the shared host pip is in version 1.1.

Comment: OK, next possibility… Could the Python 2.6 site-packages and/or dist-packages be on your `sys.path` even in your Python 2.7? Run your Python and `print sys.path` to see. If it is, we need to figure out why and fix that.

Comment: No it's not... it is clearly running the version from 2.6 despite the fact `which` is saying otherwise... `python` is running all right. Using `/home/user/python27/bin/pip` is working correctly.

Comment: Next idea: Let's make sure that it's not something funky in your shell. Compare `pip --version`, `$(which pip) --version`, and `env pip --version`. Are they all wrong, or just one of them?

Comment: Meanwhile… would using virtualenv be an acceptable alternative? Assuming you can get `virtualenv` installed into your Python 2.7 and create a venv with it (which may require some explicit absolute paths), there's at least a chance that everything will work within the venv (without ever having to do those explicit absolute paths again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may change your `PATH` variable so that your `/home/mgx/python27/bin` is searched first. Add the following line to you `.bashrc` and souce it afterward.

```
PATH=/home/mgx/python27/bin:$PATH
```

Then

```
source .bashrc
```

Or you could just alias pip in your `.bashrc`

```
alias pip='/home/mgx/python27/bin/pip'
```

I think this would fix it.

Comment: Clearly this isn't the problem, or `which python` and `which pip` wouldn't give him the right information.

Comment: I think if he could paste here what `$PATH` maybe helpful.

Comment: PATH is like in this answer - export PATH=$PYTHONPATH:PATH and PYTHONPATH is /home/mgx/python27/bin.

Comment: Are you sure `PATH` is not changed somewhere else? What's the output of `echo $PATH`?